# How do i deal with a 500 internal server error when parsing xml through php?

Tags: php, simplexml

So, how would i go about checking a 500 internal server error, then printing a message like

```
if(errormessage){
//print custom message
} else
{
// continue with code
}
```

Something like that? How would i be able to do that?
Currently i'm parsing xml with simplexml and for some stuff its parsing from certain profiles it gives a 500 error.

I basically want to print a message if it comes across the error, else continue with execution.

the errors i get are

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6
```

`Warning: simplexml_load_string(): in F:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6`

`Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in F:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6`

`Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7`

Thank you.

Comment: First you have to determine what the error actually is. Look in your server log. Add some debugging statements to the program. Once you know what to look for, you can try to detect the error.

Answer (score 2):

surround with try catch and print your message in catch block

[Exception Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)